# Convenient place to put a change log

Tags: java, android

I am an old school C programmer and I have the habbit of putting my change log in comments at the top of my main source file.

I would like to put my change log in a more convenient place so that I could pull it up at run time and display it to the user on request.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a folder "raw" in the resource folder and store your own files there - also text files. A file "res/raw/changelog.txt" gets an identifier `R.raw.changelog` in your Java code, you then can open and read the file using `getResources().openRawResource()`. :-)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29

Comment: raw file was the first option a considered but if I put text in a raw resource, it does not seems to be compressed in the apk file. If I open the apk file with an editor (that can display hex files) I can see the text I placed in the changelog in plane text. If I put the same text in a string resource, I can't find it in the apk (it get compressed I think)

Comment: I just tought it would be :o)

Answer (score 2):

Most projects keep the change log in a file called `Changelog` in the project root.

Often this file is created manually: Developers are often ... "creative" when committing things and/or comments like "Reduced global variables", "Organized imports", etc. don't make much sense to the user.

In your case, I suggest to put the file next to the class which displays it or in the root of your (re-)source folder. That way, you can easily load it using `About.class.getResourceAsStream("Changelog")` (relative to `About`) or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Changelog")` (relative to source root folder)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to put it in an html file on the filesystem under assets.  Then in the Activity in which you want to display the change log, just use the following web view code:

```
    WebView changeLogWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ChangeLogWebView);
    InputStream fin = null;
    try {
        fin = getAssets().open("changelog.html");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
        fin.read(buffer);
        String contents = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        changeLogWebView.loadData(contents, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (fin != null) {
            try {
                fin.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tend to use html for this and about pages to make it "prettier".

Comment: is there an advantage to place the file in the assets rather than in the raw resources ?

Comment: I can't find the WebView view in the palette of the Graphical Layout (ADT r9).

Comment: I don't know that there's an advantage to assets rather than raw resources, that's just how I happened to do it.  I also don't use graphical layout tools, I just hand code my UIs, so I can't help you there.

Comment: I  hand coded the WebView also but I was wondering if it was a problem with my ADT setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://code.google.com/p/android-change-log/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your application is structured, you could put an "About" menu tab or something similar and have a changelog button that brings up your change log when it is clicked. Then you could just read the local changelog and copy over it whenever you make changes to keep it updated. Maybe something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that combines mreichelt's and Micah's answers. Thanks

Text in a raw resource dispayed in a WebView.

```
    WebView computerWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.changelog_webview);
    InputStream istream = null;
    String strLine;
    StringBuilder strbText = new StringBuilder();
    try
        {
        istream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.changelog_html);
        InputStreamReader isreader = new InputStreamReader(istream);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(isreader);
        while ((strLine = myReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
            strbText.append(strLine);
            }
        computerWebView.loadData(strbText.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        computerWebView
                .loadData("No data to display", "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    finally
        {
        if (istream != null)
            try
                {
                istream.close();
                }
            catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
        }
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to directly plug the stream in WebView.loadData()